# You have an error in your SQL syntax; for the right syntax to use near 'constraint PassID check (PassID like ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')), '

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
/*=====Table Passenger=====*/
create table Passenger(
    PassID char(6) not null primary key
    constraint PassID
    check (PassID like ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
    PassName varchar(100) not null,
    No_KTP int not null,
    Adress varchar(100) not null,
    No_Telp varchar(20) not null
);
```

Problem:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint PassID
check (PassID like ('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
...' at line 4

i tried to give semicolon after 'PassID' (before 'check') and still error

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? Versions before 8.0 ignore CHECK anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.